# Android - Can't use traceview

Tags: android, android-traceview

I am trying to use traceview to run some profiling against an Android application. I have wrapped the code that I want to trace with the following lines:

```
Debug.startMethodTracing("xxx");
// code
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

It successfully generated a trace file, that I pulled from sdcard using the following command line:

> ./adb pull /sdcard/xxx.trace

However when running `traceview` like this:

> ./traceview /.../xxx.trace

I am getting the following error message:

> Usage: java
>   com.android.traceview.MainWindow [-r]
>   trace   -r   regression only

I cannot understand this error message and I didn't find anything useful on Google.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used Traceview from the command line. If you're an Eclipse user, you can open the trace from Eclipse and bring it up in the Eclipse edition of Traceview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that Debug class you imported is this one : `android.os.Debug`

or do this :

```
android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing("xxx");
android.os.Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

Comment: The code doesn't matter for this issue actually, the command doesn't work. (And yes I am using the correct Debug class)